# Make a Facebook list with people that speak the same language

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to make a new friend list on Facebook to include all those who speak the same language?

Answer (score 2):

There's no automated way to do this from within Facebook - you can search for

> friends who speak `<language>`

[image: search results for friends who speak a language]

and click on the people tab, it'll give you a list which matches your search criteria. You can then manually add them to a list. This, however, assumes that your contacts have mentioned in their profile that they speak the particular language.

Comment: This looks like a good option. However, I never receive any results. Facebook always gives "No results found for your query."

Comment: yeah, FB is not making any smart determination based on posts users actually read.  This feature is useless I got probably 20-20% of the actual